# elastic4s build query from JSON source

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

Is there a way to build a query in [`elastic4s`](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s) from a JSON string?

For example, something like:

```
client.execute { "{ \"query\": ..., \"aggs\": ..., ... }" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't support a truly raw query in the sense of passing a string to `client.execute`. This is because the execute method wraps the Java client, and the Java client provides seperate methods per request type.

But you can pass in a raw query string, so something like:

```
search in "*" types("users", "tweets") limit 5 rawQuery {
 +  """{ "prefix": { "bands": { "prefix": "coldplay", "boost": 5.0, "rewrite": "yes" } } }"""
```